# How to Edit in Datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using Datatables(https://datatables.net) with jQuery in html page. I am very new to Datatable api as well as to JQuery.The relevant portion of code is as below:

```
//Some Code...
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                                    id="dataTables-companyGroupFilter">
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="companyGroupFilterDetails">
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Some Code...
var dataTableGroupCompany = $('#dataTables-companyGroupFilter').DataTable({
     'sDom' : 'tp',
     "bDeferRender": true,
     "aoColumns": [
                   {"sClass": "col1" },
                   {"sClass": "col2" },
                   null,
                   null,
                 ],
     "iDisplayLength" : 20}).rowGrouping({
        bExpandableGrouping:true, iGroupingColumnIndex:3, 
        fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){
            if(mapCompany[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapCompany[label]+")"; else return label; }});
//Some Code...
dataTableGroupCompany.fnAddData(
                                        ["<img src='"+pic+"' style='height: 80px;' class='person-link' person-uri='"+value["uri"]+"'>",
                                         "&nbsp; <br><i class='" + employmentCssClass + "' style='padding-top: 5px;'></i><br><i class='" + placeCssClass + "' style='padding-top: 5px;'></i> <br><i class='" + organisationCssClass + "' style='padding-top: 3px;'></i>",
                                         "<b><a class='person-link' person-uri='"+value["uri"]+"'>"+name+"</a></b> <br>"+desig+"<br>"+place+"<br>"+organisation, organisation,mapCompany[organisation]],false);
```

Where last columns `mapCompany[organization]` is nothing but integers.

What I want to do is to iterate each and every row and replace 4th column using data of 3rd column as a key in Hashmap i.e mapCompany[organisation] where organization could be a key in 3rd column.

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I want to edit last column in every row.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Ok. I am waiting for your ans.

Comment: i just updated my answer this will be more easy for you.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callback for each row created while drawing the table:

```
"fnCreatedRow" : function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    $('td:last-child', nRow).text(100);
}
```

check out the fiddle i just created : http://jsfiddle.net/yrn2nfj3/

Comment: $('td:eq(nth column)', nRow).val(100); something like that

Comment: I had given just an example. I want to set any nth row, also the data I need to set may by different for each row.

Comment: do you have a function that will add values to specific rows?

Comment: I have hashmap mapping with mapCompany[organisation], where organisation is already in 3rd column.

Comment: Check out the fiddle bro

Comment: That was nice one bro. Just last question. I have already set all datatable parameters and at the end of adding data using dt.fnAddData() method I can just determine my HashmMap values. How can I set again "fnCreatedRow" parameter in current instance of table to refresh it?

Comment: when you initialize the datatable and added the fnCreatedRow callback, it will automatically be triggered if you refresh or redraw the table. just give it a try.

Comment: Bro, Please see my conversations with frebin francis. I have datat for 4th column only at the end of all records (atleast for a group) are added.

Comment: I really don't get it. I just understood that you will change a value of a certain column of each row (example : 4th column), which will depend on a map where the key is in another column (3rd column for example).

Comment: Yes but I dont have Hashmap until Table data is filled up.

Comment: Then I think you just need to redraw the datatable. I created a map in the fiddle just for example and didn't know where and when your map is populated.

Comment: Thanks bro. Can I ask u one more thing? I am unable to see my last column. Can you please help?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot see your last column? I have tried this one with the fiddle and got the last column values:   console.log($('td:last-child', nRow).text());

Comment: I mean as per my code I showed here, I can't see last columns of Hashmap. Do I need to do something with aoColumns for the same?